# How I can set timer on a single line code in java

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, timeoutexception, transport

My requirements is.. I want to set a timer on a single line code in java. If time exceeded then it will throw a timeout exception and it will start to execute that single line code into a different thread.

Here is my code

```java
public Object ShootSMTPMail(String subject,String body,Session session,SMTPServerInfo smtpserverInfo,InternetAddress[] mailAddress_TO) throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(smtpserverInfo.SMTPUsername));
            
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, mailAddress_TO);
            
            message.setSubject(subject);
            
            message.setContent(body, "text/html");
            
            Transport.send(message);// I want to set a timer on this line;
         
            
            return true;
        }
               
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
        finally
        {
            
        }
    }
```

Basically here I am sending emails through Transport.send(), and this statement taking some time to execute, So I want to throw a timeout exception to the font end and want to show the user that it will take some times to execute. and meanwhile I want to execute Transport.send(message); this line in different thread and when I will receive response from Transport.send(message); this execution I will send it to font end. Actually I want make this whole process asynchronous. Please help me..

Comment: Why do you want to make the backend asynchronous for that? Why not just wait in the front end (and use setTimeout to display some message to the user if it takes longer than expected)

Comment: In any circumstances .I have to execute Transport.send(message); this line. I can't end the process..

Answer (score 0):

In java things like that are usually implemented as a service with internal pool of threads.

Something like that:

```java
public class EmailSenderService {

  private ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.new***Pool();

  public Future<?> send(Message message) {
    return threadPool.submit(() -> Transport.send(message));
  }

  public void shutDownService() {
    threadPool.shutdownNow();
    ...
  }
}
```

Here `Transport.send(message)` is executing asynchronously in another thread, while the `Future` instance returned by `send()` allows the caller to check if the task has finished, to cancel the task, etc.